# <h1><%= text %></h1> reference error text is not defined ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So i am making something for fun and i am new to express.js and ejs i made a minecraft server status checker and i want to display the result in  <%=text%> from express.js but i am getting this error

```
ReferenceError: C:\Users\UwU\OneDrive\Desktop\UwU web\Web Development\Firebones-Site\views\index.ejs:110
    108|         <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 

    109|     </form> 

 >> 110|     <h1><%= text %></h1>

    111|     </div>

    112|   </body>

    113|   <script src="js/effect.js"></script>


text is not defined
```

my index.ejs

```
 <form action="/" method="GET"> 
        <input type="text" name="uwu" required /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 
    <h1><%= text %></h1>
```

express (main.js)

```
//Imports
const express = require("express");
const res = require("express/lib/response");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require("path");
const util = require('minecraft-server-util')
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "public/css"));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "public/js"));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + "public/img"));
app.set("views", "./views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");   
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
  var input = req.query.uwu;
  util.status(input)
  .then((response) => {
    var players = response.players.online;
    var maxplayers = response.players.max;    
    res.render("index", {text: players} )
  })    
});
```

Comment: Well, it's telling the truth, I don't see where you're defining a variable named `text`, right?

Comment: yes its true i am new to ejs can you tell me how to define  variable `text`

Comment: Oh, well the problem is you're rendering "index" twice for some reason. You have `res.render("index");` (incorrect) and `res.render("index", {text: players} )` (correct). I'd remove the first render.

Comment: now i am getting a new error `(node:8164) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected 'host' to be a 'string', got 'undefined'` i updated the code to  `app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var input = req.query.uwu;
  util.status(input)
  .then((response) => {
    var players = response.players.online;
    var maxplayers = response.players.max;    
    res.render("index", {text: players} )
  
  })
  

});`

Answer (score -3):

Try to use ejs package version 3.16: npm install ejs@3.1.6